# Java arrays Highest/Average/Median/Mode

Tags: java, arrays

Had trouble with printing the median, average and mode correctly. All it took was some moving around of coding and a few number/word changes!!

Program:

```
 public static int StudentAverage(int [] array)
        //almost there, some random big code is in front of the wording?
    {
      int avg;
      int sum=0;
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       sum=sum+array[i];
    }
    avg=sum/4;
    System.out.println("The average is: " +avg);
    return avg;

    }

    public static int median(int [] array) {
    //i think this is way off also
    int size = 0;
    int[] grades = new int [size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    grades[i]=0;
        }

        int i;  
        for( i=0;i<size;++i){
            int count=0;    
            for (int j=0;j<size;++j){
                if(grades[i]>grades[j]){
                    count++;

                }
            }   
            if(count==grades.length/4){
                break;

            }
        System.out.print("The median is: "+grades[i]);
        }

                return grades[i];
    }
    public static int mode(int [] array) {
    int maxValue = 0, maxCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; ++j) {
            if (array[j] == array[i]) ++count;
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = array[i];
        }
    }

    return maxValue;
```

Client:

```
public class StudentGradesClient {
public static void main(String [] args){
    int [] grades = new int [4]; 
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
            {
                grades[i] = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
            }
            StudentGrades.AscendingSort(grades);  
            System.out.println ("Student Grades");
            for (int i = 0; i<grades.length; i++)
                System.out.print(grades[i] + "\t");
                    System.out.println();

            StudentGrades.Highest(grades); 
            for (int i = 1; i < grades.length; i++)
            System.out.print(grades[i]);



           StudentGrades.StudentAverage(grades); 
           for (int i = 0; i<grades.length; i++)
           //some random big number keep popping up before
           System.out.println();

           //not printing at all         
           StudentGrades.median(grades);
             for (int i = 0; i<grades.length; i++)
                System.out.println();

}    
}
```

Result:

```
Student Grades
6   23  49  65  
The highest grade is: 65
234965The average is: 35


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at studentgrades.StudentGrades.median(StudentGrades.java:66)
    at studentgrades.StudentGradesClient.main(StudentGradesClient.java:32)
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**EDIT**

I'm almost there! The hints are extremely helpful! Now, I'm having difficulty with finishing off the median and modes, as well there is a big number that keeps showing before my average print.

If anyone can just post hints and such - I do not request a direct answer. I am learning from the help/hints being shared so thank you! Still a bit confused on some parts and would greatly appreciate it - thank you again!

Comment: What's the error? OutOfBounds? NPE? With the for loop starting 1 it might be

Comment: Some tips for posting homework questions: firstly, they are very welcome, and it is good that you are not asking for someone to do it for you. However if you dump obviously copy+pasted material from your educator without declaring it explicitly as homework, it raises suspicions - possibly unfairly. So, introduce it, say what you are doing, and use a quote block. You have shown program and client code, but we do not know if this is your work - if it is your work then giving it some context is very helpful, e.g. "here is what I have tried".

Comment: Also, keep titles succinct and meaningful please - "need some assistance please" is fairly implicit, and does not need to go in. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: oh whoops - youre right. it definitely is my work, but didnt think to label all that you mentioned as such. i'll surely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

- In the `Highest` method, look at where your `println` is relative to the loop that computes `max` (further hint: it's not **after** the loop)
- Why are you not passing your `grades` array to `StudentAverage()` and `median()`
- In `StudentAverage()`, why looping 100 times and dividing the computed sum by 100?

New hints:

- that "random" big number printing in front of the average isn't random at all.  Give it a closer look...
- from the assignment: "The median grade will be located in the middle of the sorted array of grades".

Comment: Thank you so much for the hints! It truly has helped. I edited my question now to where I'm still having trouble with.

Comment: finally got it! truly want to say thank you for helping me out there.